# Populate combobox with data from JSON file

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms

I am attempting to build what I think should be a relatively simply reader/editor for a very specifically formatted JSON file mostly as a way to prevent users from messing up the syntax.

Json format is:

```
"Items": {
"defaultActionClass": "Weaponclass",
"ItemObjects": [
  {
    "Id": "M16",
    "Name": "EM16",
    "Description": "Some Description",
    "Icon": "Icons/pictures/1.png",
    "AnimationSet": "Set1",
    "Type": "Weapon",
    "EquipmentClass": "Hands",
    "SlotsCount": 2,
    "Weight": 1,
    "AP": 1,
    "BurstFire": 1,
    "AutoFire": 0,
    "EffectiveRange": 8.0,
    "MuzzleVelocity": 2.5,
    "BaseAccuracy": 100.0,
    "Mobility": 6.0,
    "Damage": 30,
    "DamageFalloff": 30,
    "AmmoClips": [
      "AmmoClip556NATOx30"
    ]
  },
```

I can read in the string, that's not an issue, what I am struggling with are the following two items.

Found a way to get the ID's using the following code:

```
Dim root As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(strjson)
Dim ID As List(Of String) = root.Items.ItemObjects.Select(Of String)(Function(tp) tp.Id).ToList()
```

That returns all 60 ID's in the list, now my challenge is getting that list into the combobox.  I know I have done this before with other items but this one continues to elude me.

Smooth overthinking the combobox piece.

```
cmbWeaponID.DataSource = ID
```

Ok, now to figure out how to grab the rest of the data from each ID on the SelectedIndexChanged for the combo box and import it into different text boxes.

Managed to get that going as well with the following code:

```
        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(strjson)
    Dim Type As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Type"))
    Dim Name As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Name"))
    Dim Description As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Description"))
    Dim Icon As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Icon"))
    Dim AnimationSet As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AnimationSet"))
    Dim SlotsCount As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].SlotsCount"))
    Dim Weight As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Weight"))
    Dim APCost As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AP"))
    Dim BurstFire As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].BurstFire"))
    Dim AutoFire As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].AutoFire"))
    Dim EffectiveRange As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].EffectiveRange"))
    Dim MuzzleVelocity As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].MuzzleVelocity"))
    Dim BaseAccuracy As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].BaseAccuracy"))
    Dim Mobility As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Mobility"))
    Dim Damage As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].Damage"))
    Dim DamageFalloff As String = CStr(o.SelectToken("Items.ItemObjects[" & cmbWeaponID.SelectedIndex & "].DamageFalloff"))
```

Comment: very very easy have a look at http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: So far I have been able to pull the first ID out of the file using the 
    SelectToken("Items").SelectToken("ItemObjects[0].Id").ToString)

That gets me the first item ID but I can't seem to make a loop work to get them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while so I am very rusty but once I got the JSON into a list, all I needed was this:

```
Dim ID As List(Of String) = root.Items.ItemObjects.Select(Of String)(Function(tp) tp.Id).ToList()
cmbWeaponID.DataSource = ID
```